# where to look for previously executed commands

Tags: linux, unix

I want to understand how up/down arrow keys help to navigate through previously executed commands. which memory it access to get last executed command?

Currently i am working on unix similar Machine "Stratus VOS"  where i can see only last 1 executed command and that too with F10 key.
I want to create a script/tool  which can help to me to get at least last 10-15 executed commands to save my time during development work.

what i noticed so far on Stratus Machine:

1: fc command doesn't work.
2. no HISTFILE is maintained. no history command works.

what i thought to implement:

find which memory in system holds last executed command, access that memory(whenever Enter key is pressed ) and keep writing in file.
am i on right track? is there any better solution for this?

Comment: When you execute `history` nothing happens?

Comment: so, echo $HISTFILE doesn't give you this answer?

Comment: What is output of `echo $SHELL` on that OS?

Comment: Stratus VOS doesn't support history command.

Comment: Stratus doesn't support $HISTFILE or $SHELL. i said its unix alike because i can run all sed, awk, grep commands there.

Comment: Assuming your system is unix like, have you considered just porting a better shell to it? Assuming you have a cc for the system you can probably build bash or as least ash for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that while possible your solution is possibly overcomplex and likely to be difficult and possibly unreliable. I would instead consider using the Stratus VOS GNU tools package which includes a full GNU Bash shell with all the features you expect including the command history support.

A little documentation on GNU tools for Stratus VOS appears to be available [here](http://stratadoc.stratus.com/vos/15.1.1/r453-01/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?context=r453-01&file=ch3r453-01.html) though I would suggest contacting your vendor for more information or support.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for suggestion, i could find bash interpreter at VOS machine where i can run/practice almost every unix command.

while working in bash mode i can maintain my HISTFILE,fc command and history as i wish.however there are several Stratus VOS commands which wouldn't work in bash mode and so i cant record them anywhere. even script command is also not useful. 

if i get to know how arrow keys work in respect to display previously executed commands, would be great help to me.